# Converting a real Linux OS to a virtual machine on Windows

Tags: windows-7, linux, virtual-machine, vmware, kali-linux

I currently have Kali Linux OS installed on my machine normally (not as a virtual machine). I'll soon also install Windows 7.

I'd like to know if there is a way to convert my Kali Linux OS (with all it's memory) to be a virtual machine on VMWare on the soon-to-be-installed Windows 7?

The important thing is to keep all of the Linux OS memory (so that the VMWare machine will also have it).

Answer (score 1):

P2V is what you want. And VMWare actually [has one](http://www.vmware.com/products/converter). I used it before on a production mail server and it worked quite nicely. It writes the machine to an image which you can then toss into VMware. It has the option of copying itself, too.

Comment: Thanks, sounds just like what I need. Does it keep the memory exactly as-is? I mean, when I will load it in VMware will everything stay where it was?

Comment: No...unfortunately nothing I know of can do that. RAM cannot easily be copied P2V. All your applications and such will, though.

Comment: It's not RAM memory I ment. I'm talking about applications and their data (storage data, not RAM). So I'll change the question, will everything stay the same as if I rebooted?